# Implementing a constant header/footer on my website?

Tags: html, css, header

I have a site that uses various software - phpBB for forums, mediaWiki for wiki, my own code for other pages, etc.

Those are all different of course, but I want to implement a header and a footer into the header and footer files of that software so that I may use it site-wide.

I want to just use a php include, but I want to include an entire header/footer and its own custom CSS that won't conflict with the page's CSS. I'm able to do everything but make the CSS work properly.

Here's my HTML: http://slexy.org/view/s21HJgZCov

Here's my CSS: http://slexy.org/view/s2mH808KnV

The problem lies in that if I just used element names instead of ids and classes, the header looks and works fine. But obviously I can't use names like div or a, those will already be defined in a site's HTML. How can I not make it conflict?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to use an id specifier in your header/footer, with an id thatc can't be found in the other CSS.

For example something like :

```
<div id="GlobalNameGenericHeader">...</div>
```

Then in CSS

```
#GlobalNameGenericHeader {…}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend on how your HTML is laid out, but you can use more complicated CSS selectors based on class name or ID. So, for example, in section one, you can wrap the entire section in a div:

```
<div id="section1">
    <a href="">Blah Blah</a>
    <p>A section 1 paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And then use the following CSS rules to style just the links and paragraphs in that section:

```
#section1 a { ... }
#section1 p { ... }
```